# Hide/Remove Footer, last item in RecyclerView when reached specific max limit

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to hide the Footer when it reached `maxItem`. I've tried to set `visibility = View.Gone` but it shows white empty space, instead of completely gone, no space occupied. How make make the space completely gone?

**Screenshot**:

[image]

In my `onBindViewholder` in Adapter:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            if (holder is FooterViewHolder){   
                holder.addItemCv.rootView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                if (position == maxItem) { 
                    holder.addItemCv.rootView.visibility = View.GONE
                }
            }
```

In my `FooterViewHolder` in Adapter:

```
class FooterViewHolder(itemView:View, listener: onItemClickListener) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val addItemCv : CardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addItemCv)
}
```

In my `footer.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/addItemCv"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rounded_blue_plus_btn"/>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

use remove and notify functions in recycler to achieve this.

eg:-

```
if (position== maxItem) { 
      yourDatasetName.remove(datasetPosition-1);
      yourAdapterName.notifyItemRemoved(datasetPosition.size);
   }
```

position=the holder position

Comment: Doesn't work. Still showing empty spaces

Comment: Btw, the last item is a Footer view, it is not inside the Dataset

Comment: i have updated the answer please do check

Comment: What is datasetPosition?

Comment: datasetPosition is the your list position you can simply query listname.size to get it in kotlin

Comment: yeah that work if the FooterView is inside dataset. But my FooterView is not inside dataset. Even if my dataset is empty, FooterView is still displayed.

Answer (score 0):

**My Solution:**

**Step 1**: I've created a constant with any number:

```
private val EMPTY_VIEW = 2
```

**Step 2**:In `getItemViewType()` in Adapter. I check `if position == maxItem` and return `EMPTY_VIEW` if it reaches `maxItem`:

```
if(position == maxItem) {
    return EMPTY_VIEW
}
```

**Step 3**: I created an EmptyViewHolder:

```
class EmptyViewHolder(itemView:View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    //Do Nothing, Empty
}
```

**Step 4**: I created an `empty_item.xml` where it occupies no space:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Step 5**: In my `onCreateViewHolder` I check if `viewType = EMPTY_VIEW`, and return the layout inflated with the empty_item.xml:

```
if (viewType == EMPTY_VIEW) {
    view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.empty_item, parent, false)
    return EmptyViewHolder(view)
}
```